# How to check a sub-list for null or empty in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**I have a list of questions which contains all the object of question classes and its associated with helpboxes and answers.**

While generating the UI I am having valid value range is empty exception because there are no helpboxes or answers for some of the questions.

[Image of emulator where you can see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3iw.png)

Can any one please help me out that how to add a condition like

```
if (form[index].helpboxes != null) 
    {
     label: Text(
       form[index].helpboxes[0].helpboxText,
     )
    }
else { //donot show filterchip }
```

**My code for UI where I am showing filterchips**

```
ListView questionList() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: form.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(232, 232, 232, 1),
        elevation: 0.0,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  form[index].questionNo.toString() +
                      '. ' +
                      form[index].questionText.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  ),
                ),
                FittedBox(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FilterChip(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                        label: Text(
                        here -->  **form[index].helpboxes[0].helpboxText,** <-- here
                        ),
                        onSelected: (b) {},
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      // FilterChip(
                      //   backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                      //   label: Text(
                      //     form[index].medName,
                      //   ),
                      //   onSelected: (b) {},
                      // )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          children: form[index].answers.map((m) {
            List<Answer> ans = form[index].answers;
            // for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
            //   if (form[index].questionId == 3) {
            //     print(index);
            //   }
            // }
            return AnswerWidget(ans, index, m);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

*Thanks in advance :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (form[index].helpboxes?.isNotEmpty == true) FilterChip(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
    label: Text(
    form[index].helpboxes[0].helpboxText,
    ),
    onSelected: (b) {},
),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can add it easly in your children List

```
if(form[index].helpboxes != null && form[index].helpboxes[0] != null)
    FilterChip(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                            label: Text(
                           form[index].helpboxes[0].helpboxText,
                            ),
                            onSelected: (b) {},
                          ),
```

Comment: try to check if form[index].helpboxes[0] != null